# Rails on Local machine with no nginx or apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am on the starting level of rails development. Recently i have been studying about web servers like puma, unicorn, webrick.

On the production level we need apache or nginx to handle the load balancing and processing the requests, my question is on my development machine i have no apache or nginx installed but how my rails project is working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apache / Nginx serves a static files: css, js, html pages and etc.
They do it very good, and thus they're used for the production servers with high-load file traffic.

For self purpose we are need not much, thus we are satisfied with basic tools for development, such as embedded "file server" in webric or puma or unicorn.

Not make sure that I'm right, it's a kind of magic, probably somebody has more information?